# Mathematical formula for calculating combinations of different size between sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I'm sure this has been asked before, so apologies in advance. I am unsure what this might be called so I was unable to find an answer.

Suppose there are *n* sets of *m* elements. For example:

```
Set 1: {a, b, c, d}
Set 2: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Set 3: {!, @, #}
...
```

I am looking for a formula to calculate every single combination of items between the sets, including combinations of 1 up to *n* sets (1 element, 2 elements, 3 elements, etc. combinations). For example, some possible combinations:

a, b, c, a1, a2, a3, a1!, a1@, a1#, and so on.

The string does not need to begin with an element from Set 1. It can be 'b@', 'c!', etc. and can also skip sets in between. The combination '@b' would be equivalent to 'b@' and should not be considered a different combination.

It seems like it is to a higher order than multiplication, and similar but not exactly factorial.

Is there a name for this problem and is there a formula to calculate the number of combinations as described above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I follow, but suppose I add a "blank" element to each of your sets (indicating that no element from that set is chosen).  using your three sets, we'd get $5\times 6\times 4$ strings.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Your list of examples suggests that the string must begin with an element from Set $1$, but I suppose that was unintended?  Just to specify:  is the empty string a valid combination?  Is $2$?

Comment: @lulu Yes, the string does not need to begin with an element from Set 1 and could be "blank". It can be 'b@'. The combination '@b' would be equivalent and shouldn't be considered. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @lulu Sets in the middle can also be skipped, such that combinations of 'a@', 'a#', etc. are possible.

Comment: So, then my formula is correct, no?  If set $i$ has $n_i$ elements then the answer is $\prod (n_i+1)$.

Comment: I just worked out some examples on paper and it checks out! Because 3 blanks would not be considered a combination, I would simply subtract 1 from the formula. Thank you for the help! I swore it seemed more complicated than that. :P